# Dotnet core with Angular window is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular, .net-core, angular-universal

It works fine when i run with node Express server (I use @ng-toolkit/universal) But with aspnet core node engine throwing NodeInvocation Exception Reference Error: Window is not defined in a third party modules like ngx-bootstrap and angular-jwt.

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed         
because of error: ReferenceError: window is not 
defined
at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\2ndCustomer\Angular6\node_modules\@auth0\angular- 
jwt\bundles\core.umd.js:1:704)
```

And ngx-bootstrap error but when i run with express server.ts it works fine
https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit